# My question was closed unfairly as 'not clear'

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Old HDDs aren't being detected — even in the BIOS — on my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1531235/old-hdds-arent-being-detected-even-in-the-bios-on-my-computer)

I asked the above question about HDD, but my question was closed as, 'Needs details or clarity'.  Considering that, I edited my question to make it more clear. In other words, 'Written more clearly, the problem I would like to solve.'

After that I received a comment, and having replied to it, I again edited my question. Then, that user still asked me to edit my question, [even when I had edited it earlier already]. Anyway, even then I edited my question [even after it was clear enough]. In other words, 'Tried to make my question even more clear'.

Then I received a comment from another user, and considering the suggestion, I again 'grand'-edited my question, even though I didn't received a reply to my comment from that user. After that, I still made little edits. In other words, '...: made some little changes,... earlier...: added much info to make the question even more clear.'

After making the question clearest, finally, when I observed, it is still not re-opened, I asked in the comments so that anyone might reply, [but, after not receiving any replies], I asked one of the folks who closed it, for, what needs to be done now, but I didn't received a reply even then also. And I would like to stress that I have already read about writing questions, *and after my final edit, I can't see any more room for further clarity in the question*.

And in the 1 'answer' to my question [which wasn't of much help], I informed/asked the folks who closed my question, that, I have edited my question, so that it might be re-opened, but I got no response.

And, what is bad towards me is, when I have edited my question several times, even when I am stuck with my not-working HDDs with the data 'caged' in them because they aren't working, and so I wanted quick help so that I could take any further action, and then if I receive no replies to my queries about why my question is still closed, `n the question also doesn't get re-opened, then it is like being bossy on one, whose question wasn't considered clear by the folks, even though I have replied to folks about what they asked.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105781/discussion-on-question-by-user928474-my-question-was-closed-unfairly-as-not-cle).

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I have a question about comments. My comments got deleted automatically (not by 'moved to chat') as the comments were increasing, but however, I wanted to see them, and I read a question at this site, mentioning, that moderators can see deleted comments, so can you help me with that?

Comment: the comments are all in the [linked chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105781/discussion-on-question-by-user928474-my-question-was-closed-unfairly-as-not-cle)

Comment: @SathyajithBhat What 'linked chat'?, that is a twitter link which you gave.

Comment: corrected the link, it's the same as in my first comment

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I checked your first link which is named 'moved to chat', _but_, the [starting] comments which were deleted (_as I don't see them now_) are _not_ even in that link.

Answer (score 4):

Great question!  I'm going to look at your original more and see if I can help!  Thank you for trying to re-open it!

Your question might be wordy and hyper-analytical.  By that I mean, you might be analyzing to the point that you miss some of your own mistakes.  Be patient with me, I think your question is sufficiently clear to be understood and deserves to be answered, but if you adjust your style your question will be more appealing.

Here is an excepts:

> I have a total of 4 disks (2 SSDs, and 2 HDDs). The three (2 SSDs (are
>   in use), and 1 HDD (*was in use* [because it is not working now (as
>   explained below)])).

Here, you didn't finish the second sentence.  Also, you used a mathematical style of triple-bracketing that resulted in an extraneous bracket.  It can be understood without being hyper-clarified.  This is a rephrasing: "Three of the harddrives (2 SSD's and 1 HDD)...".

I removed the fact that isn't pertinent to this paragraph because it's mentioned later and redundancy is seldom appreciated in academic and technical writing; so, you don't need to say that it is broken.  And, it just trails off, just like the original...

So, the first paragraph or two are going to make or break you when you write something, you know?  Even if the rest of the article is great, the first and last paragraphs are premier.

Anyway, if you get a recommendation to rewrite you should just do it.  Usually, questions are re-opened on SE.

Also, it was a little bit chatty.  Look up a support ticket and try to phrase your question like a support ticket if you're posing a support question.   Keep it dry and technical with as little irrelevant info as possible.

```
System info:
Problem:
Expected behavior:
Actual behavior:
What you tried:
Summary:
```